# CSS h1 spotted/dotter border

Tags: html, css

I have the following code that sets a dotted/spotted bottom border on 'h1' tags.

The full code can be found at moorparksdevon.uk

```
h1 {
    padding: 0 0 7px 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    display:table;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 33%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%);
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: 3px 1px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

However... I don't appear to have consistent results in the slightest. Am I missing something here?

Safari Mac - Lots of dots working (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAHgm.jpg)

Firefox Mac - Some dots working (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzRTM.png)

Chrome Mac - No dots at all (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sYfL.jpg)

Comment: Scott, please include all of your code and reproduce the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve It looks fine to me in chrome, firefox, and safari http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KaezJQ

Comment: I've included a URL - I'm going to struggle to reproduce the problem if you'r seeing it fine... I've posted the screenshots showing three different dotted borders.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use CSS `border-bottom` to set a dotted border.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mmkctq59/